# Mahout KMeans generate doubled cluster number than my initial K setting

Tags: mahout, k-means

I am a beginner in Mahout, I use Mahout 0.8 and followed the tutorial in https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/clustering-of-synthetic-control-data.html

When I use :
`mahout org.apache.mahout.clustering.syntheticcontrol.kmeans.Job -i testdata -o output -t1 20 -t2 50 -k 5 -x 20 -ow`

then use clusterdump to extract the cluster-centers:

```
mahout clusterdump --input output/clusters-20-final --output /media/synthetic_control.center
```

in the synthetic_control.center file:

```
VL-585{n=50 c=[29.832, 29.589, 29.405, 28.516, 29.600, ….] r=[3.152, 3.518, 3.292, …]}

VL-591{n=197 c=[29.984, 29.681,…] r=[3.602, 3.558, 3.364,…]}

VL-595{n=203 c=[….] r=[….]}

VL-597{n=61 c=[….] r=[….]}

VL-599{n=43 c=[….] r=[….]}

VL-585{n=1 c=[….] r=[….]}

VL-591{n=27 c=[….] r=[….]}

VL-595{n=1 c=[….] r=[….]}

VL-597{n=1 c=[….] r=[….]}

VL-599{n=16 c=[….] r=[….]}
```

It seems the kmean generates 10 clusters, but my initial setting for k is 5.

I also tried other k, it always generate doubled clusters.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Shoudln't you choose `t1 > t2`?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: yes, thanks for the notice. Indeed, t1 should > t2. These parameters are used for canopy-clustering, as cluster-number K is set, the job will not run canopy clustering before kmeans, but run kmean directly, so t1 and t2 doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haha! finally, after reading the code, I found the bug in mahout org.apache.mahout.clustering.syntheticcontrol.kmeans.Job!!

here is the thing:
in syntheticcontrol.kmeans.Job, if user set k, then the job will not run canopy clustering before kmeans, but run kmean directly.
when run kmean, it needs initial centers for each cluster, so it use RandomSeedGenerator to random generate the each cluster center and put this file(part-randomSeed) to **output/clusters-0 folder**, after this kmean first use these centers to classify all the points and renew the cluster center and put these centers to  **output/clusters-0 folder**. So, in clusters-0 folder, there are two set of centers!! Thus, first iteration will read doubled clusters! this is why this job always generate doubled cluster number!

solution: save part-randomSeed to another folder.
in org.apache.mahout.clustering.syntheticcontrol.kmeans.Job

line 142,    `Path clusters = new Path(output, Cluster.INITIAL_CLUSTERS_DIR);`

change to  `Path clusters = new Path(output, "randomSeeds");`

Comment: The only way of making sure that this is a bug is reporting it.